# Every message I send from client to server ends with NullPointerException. how do I fix it?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, server, network-programming

I am doing a sort of test run for the networked portion of an application I am building, and I am running into a problem where every message I send from the client to the server has null attached to the end of it. So for example "hello" would be printed by the server as "hellonull".

The actual application needs to be able to send commands that the server will read. this test only prints the message. I have found that this is a problem with a `NullPointerException` but what I don't understand is where `null` is coming from. Is it the end of the stream? I thought that the end of stream would be indicated by -1. And if `null` does indicate the end of the stream how do I exit the stream without reaching `null`?

This is the main class for the server:

```
package servertester;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ServerLaunch {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        final int PORT = 4444;
        final int NUM_THREADS = 50;

            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);

            try(ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(PORT)){
                while(true){
                    try{
                        Socket con = serv.accept();
                        Runnable r = new      ServerRunnable(con);
                        Future<?> future = pool.submit(r);
                        String msg = (String) future.get();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }


    }

}
}
}
```

This is the Runnable class:

```
package servertester;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ServerRunnable implements Runnable{

private Socket con;

ServerRunnable(Socket con){
    this.con = con;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    InputStream in;
    try {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        in = con.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(bin);

        for(int c = reader.read(); c != -1; c = reader.read()){

            str.append((char) c);
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }catch(NullPointerException n){
        System.out.println("np");
    }
        catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("io");

        }finally{
            if(con != null)
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }


    }



}
```

Thanks in advance for the help...

Comment: Messages do not end with `NullPointerExceptions`, and there is no evidence of it in your question. What there is is the unexpected *text* `null` at the end of your message, and this does *not* result from a `NullPointerException`. Please clarify your question and title. Please also show the *sending* code.

Answer (score -1):

Socket con = serv.accept();
 you need a instance Socket for the method accept(),because if there haven't any client (Socket instance) ,it may throw nullpointerexception in your code

Comment: ok. do I need the new Socket instance in my Runnable class, or somewhere in the main class... could you clarify a little?

Comment: as far as i am concerned, your Runnable is a kind of service on your service

Comment: There is no way this code can throw a `NullPointerException` because of anything to do with `con`. He should *not* have an instance `Socket` member in `ServerLaunch`, as this would make his `ServerLaunch` class non-reentrant.

Comment: thanks... I figured it out. the problem was the future.get(). that was returning null. I just removed it.